# Heroku - No bower_components folder

Tags: angularjs, heroku, deployment, bower

I'm deploying an Angular app to Heroku, and I need bower to add the Angular component and a few others. Deployment is working, everything except the deployed site is missing the bower_components folder. I've been through everything, and read many StackOverflow posts, but I must be missing something. Here is my code:

package.json

```
 {
   "name": "my-webapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.8.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node web.js",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com...."
  },

  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com..."
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com...",
  "description": ""
}
```

web.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html', {root: __dirname })
});
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

Procfile

```
web: node web.js
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "my-webapp",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "authors": [
    "Me"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://my-webapp.herokuapp.com/",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-material-icons": "^0.7.1",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.1",
    "materialize": "^0.97.8",
    "ng-lodash": "^0.5.0"
  }
```

Here is the build output, edited highlights :

```
-----> Building dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       bower@1.8.0 /tmp/build_9a163093ad395af381c984026f6a5742/me-my-webapp-bfae0f9/node_modules/bower
       express@4.15.2 /tmp/build_9a163093ad395af381c984026f6a5742/mugwag-my-webapp-bfae0f9/node_modules/express
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components
-----> Build succeeded!

-----> Rebuilding any native dependencies
       bower@1.8.0 /tmp/build_9a163093ad395af381c984026f6a5742/me-my-webapp-bfae0f9/node_modules/bower
       express@4.15.2 /tmp/build_9a163093ad395af381c984026f6a5742/me-my-webapp-bfae0f9/node_modules/express
????????? bower@1.8.0 
npm WARN my-webapp@1.0.0 No description
-----> Found bower.json, running bower install
-----> Installing dependencies

       > my-webapp@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_9a163093ad395af381c984026f6a5742/me-my-webapp-bfae0f9
       > ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install

       npm WARN my-webapp@1.0.0 No description
```

To me, it looks as though everything is working, but when I load the page, I get a load of broken links to the bower_components folder like this :

> Cannot GET /bower_components/materialize/dist/css/materialize.css

There is no bower folder. Why!?

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I never solved this problem, but now use Amazon S3 to host Angular apps. Because Angular is entirely client-side, no server is needed. Just upload the code to S3 or similar, plain hosting and reference it directly.

I hope that helps someone.